# Sublime Text: regreplace - move entire tag above another tag

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3, regex-group

Not sure if this is possible.

What I want to do is move an entire tag with its content above another tag.

For example:

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p class="para">Test</p>
```

I want to move the p and its content  above the table so end result would be:

```
<p class="para">Test</p>
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So simply don't know how to move it. I can capture the p by doing this regex:

```
 (?P<test><p class=\"para\">(.*?)(</p>))
```

I can also capture the entire table:

```
(<table (.*?)>)(.*?)(</table>))
```

So not sure if you can move it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:`(\<table(?:.*\n)+\<\/table>)\n(\<p(?:.*?)\<\/p>)`

Replace with: `$2\n$1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J7CZeq/1)

Comment: The regex is different for regreplace on Sublime Text but I amended and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: **Solution**
Regex: (?si)(<table (.*?)>(.*?)</table>)\n\t*(<p (.*?)>(.*?)</p>)
Replace: \\4\n\\1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, use unpacking and `str.join`:

```
s = """
 <table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<p class="para">Test</p>
"""
*data, target = filter(None, s.split('\n'))
new_html = '{}\n{}'.format(target, '\n'.join(data))
```

Ouptut:

```
<p class="para">Test</p>
<table class="table1">
 <tr>
  <td>A</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you do this on sublime text 3 - regreplace package?